# How do I select multiple fields in mysql json query?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am running MySQL with JSON support. This query works as expected.

First my attributes field.

```
{"Color1": "Blue", "Color2": "White", "Color3": "Black", "Color4": "Red"}
```

And query.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.Color1')) AS Color1 FROM     
my_table");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $Color1 = $row['Color1'];
```

Now to the question, how do I get Color1 and Color2 in a single query?

Maybe I was unclear. Look at this query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.Color1', '$.Color2')) AS multiple_colors FROM     
my_table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$multiple_colors = $row['multiple_colors'];
```

The answer is in the array multiple_colors but i can not figure out how to get the values from the array.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"Now to the question, how do I get Color1 and Color2 in a single query?

Maybe I was unclear. Look at this query."*   What results are you after or how should the PHP array look like it is still not very clear..

Comment: `$row['multiple_colors']` is comma separated there right? -> `var_dump($row['multiple_colors'])` ?  -> see PHP manual about `explode()`

Comment: I want the two colors in two variables. As simple as that.

Comment: This is the result I get when I select all 4 colors. ["Blue", "White", "Black", "Red"]

Comment: did you read or tryed mine last comment?  or `$row['multiple_colors']` is comma separated or a JSON array like `[Blue, White]`  then you can use string replace functions in PHP to remove those [ and ] before using `explode()` , not the best code but it works..

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, '$.Color1', '$.Color2', '$.Color3', '$.Color4')) AS multiple_colors FROM     
my_table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$multiple_colors = $row['multiple_colors'];

// put json multiple_colors to array
$multiple_colors_array = [];
$multiple_colors_array = json_decode($multiple_colors, true);
$color1 = $multiple_colors_array[0];
$color2 = $multiple_colors_array[1];
$color3 = $multiple_colors_array[2];
$color4 = $multiple_colors_array[3];
```